# Issue with IntelliJ and Tapestry

Tags: intellij-idea, tapestry

I am currently evaluating IntelliJ for a tapestry project. I setup my module to use the tapestry facet but the  following three tapestry items remain greyed out: page, component,    mixin

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance,

Julien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the community edition or the ultimate edition? I believe the tapestry integration may be disabled on the community edition.

Comment: I have purchase the ultimate edition and it now works. Thanks.